# Container view does not check UITableView data in scroll?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4, uicontainerview

I have created a container view with child ViewControllers programmatically. child view contains UITableView but I am not able to scroll UITableView(if I scroll data hides from UITableView).

```
let VC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "roomList") as! roomListViewController
VC.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (containerView?.frame.size.width)!, height: (containerView?.frame.size.height)!)
  ///  self.containerView?.isHidden = false
  self.containerView?.addSubview(VC.view)
  let flipDirection: UIViewAnimationOptions = flipped ? .transitionFlipFromTop : .transitionFlipFromBottom
  let options: UIViewAnimationOptions = [flipDirection, .showHideTransitionViews]
  UIView.transition(from: VC.view, to: VC.view, duration: 0.6, options: options) {
        finished in

    }
```

Comment: Did you set any view constraints to make sure that the child view controller is bounded within the parent view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have fixed with  addChildViewController(VC) and VC.didMove(toParentViewController: self) parent methods.my working code is

```
        let VC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "roomList") as! roomListViewController
        addChildViewController(VC)
        VC.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (containerView?.frame.size.width)!, height: (containerView?.frame.size.height)!)
        VC.delegate = self

        self.containerView?.addSubview(VC.view)
        //controller.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        VC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        let flipDirection: UIViewAnimationOptions = flipped ? .transitionFlipFromTop : .transitionFlipFromBottom
        let options: UIViewAnimationOptions = [flipDirection, .showHideTransitionViews]
        UIView.transition(from: VC.view, to: VC.view, duration: 0.6, options: options) {
            finished in

            //cardModel.flipped = !flipped
        }
```